# How to apply constraint programmatically based on simulator orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my **ViewController** I have added one **UIView** programmatically using Auto-layouts

Here I am applying constraints based on simulator orientations but here based on my code constraints only applying when simulator at portrait mode but when change it at landscape mode constraints are not applying what did I do here wrong

### my code:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController (){

    UIView * MainView;
}

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    MainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    MainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MainView];

    [self AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint];
}

-(void)AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint{

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MainView);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for MainView

    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

     [self.view setNeedsLayout];

}

-(void)AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae{

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MainView);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for MainView

    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[MainView]-10-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-10-[MainView]-10-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

     [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context){

         UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");
             [self AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint];
        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {


            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
             [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae];

        }else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

              NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");
              [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae];
        }

     } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {

     }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use size classes for your requirement. Using size classes, when designing your app, you can now create a single layout, which works on all current iOS devices – without crufty platform-specific code. All you need to do is to open storyboard, goto file inspector and make sure that the **Use Size Classes** checkbox is ticked.

**[Here is a really nice tutorial on Size Classes.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)**

Comment: thre is something i have done mistack but i can't recogniged that

Comment: It is not just about ticking it. You need to design your UI using size classes to support different screen sizes and orientations. Programatically applying constraints for different screen sizes and orientations is not at all a good idea. That is why I provided a tutorial link along with my answer. :-)

Comment: but i want to do my requirement through programatically is it not possible?

Comment: It **IS** possible, just not a good idea. I provided a better option. You are surely going to mess up the entire code and project once you have a little more views in your project. So better do it the right way from the beginning.

Comment: thrre is nothing i just inserted only one UIview in my main Viewcontroller and when i change orientation i clear constraints adding again that's it

Comment: did you not find where did i do wrong in above code?

Comment: i want everything porgramatically

Answer (score 0):

You call 2 different functions in your UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

This seems to make no sense:

```
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

          NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");
         [self AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint]; //?
    }
```